# How to make it run with loop

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to make a TNT DROPPING plugin and much more... But im very stuck at this point i made a loop but the command inside the LOOP doesnt work and crash my server (To be specific the command works but the TNT doesnt explode and also doesn't follow you)
This is my code

```
 @EventHandler
public void guiClickEvent(InventoryClickEvent e) throws InterruptedException {
    if(!e.getInventory().equals(gui)) {
        return;
    }

    e.setCancelled(true);

    Player p = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();

    switch (e.getSlot()) {
        case 1: {
            p.closeInventory();
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "TNT START DROPPING");
            for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "execute at @a run summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~40 ~ {Fuse:80}");
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            }
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Use [`BukkitRunnable`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html) to do things asynchronously. You do *not* want to interrupt the main Minecraft thread with `Thread.sleep`; that freezes the whole game.

Comment: `           long timeInSeconds = 10;
                long timeInTicks = 20 * timeInSeconds;
                new BukkitRunnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "execute at @a run summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~40 ~ {Fuse:80}");

                    }
                }.runTaskLater(this,timeInTicks); `
I tried this one but now im getting error because of `.runTaskLater(this,timeInTicks);`
cause of "plugin:this"

Comment: I cant figure out how to add the "plugin" and i get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin cannot be null` in console

Comment: Those two comments are incongruous. `this` is *never* `null`, so you cannot be getting a null error if you passed `this` for the plugin.

Comment: I figure it out i had to add ` Main plugin = (Main) JavaPlugin.getProvidingPlugin(Main.class);` and works!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add an instance of your plugin in your `JavaPlugin` class.

```java
private static Main instance;
public static Main getInstance() { return instance; } // getter

@Override
public void onEnable() {
   instance = this; // set instance
}
```

Now, use it when spigot runnable :

```java
private int i = 100;
private BukkitTask task;

@EventHandler
public void guiClickEvent(InventoryClickEvent e) throws InterruptedException {
   if(!e.getInventory().equals(gui)) {
       return;
   }

   e.setCancelled(true);

   Player p = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
   if(e.getSlot() == 1) {
      i = 100; // restart count
      task = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(Main.getInstance(), () -> {
         Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "execute at @a run summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~40 ~ {Fuse:80}");
         if(i-- == 0) {
            task.cancel();
         }
      }, 80);
   }
}
```

Why 80 ?

4000ms = 4s = 80 ticks (20 ticks = 1s)